# How to separate middleware for validation and validationResult using express in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I would like to add validation for each route but in another middleware get validationResult. My code is:

**AuthValidation.js**

```
const { check } = require('express-validator');

module.exports = {
    login: [
        check("email").notEmpty().withMessage("Email is required").isEmail().withMessage("Enter a valid email"),
        check("password").notEmpty().withMessage("Password is required")
    ]
};
```

**ValidationMiddleware.js**

```
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array({ onlyFirstError: true }) });
    }
    next();
};
```

**AuthRoute.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const AuthController = require("../controllers/AuthController");
const AuthValidation = require("../validations/AuthValidation");
const validationMiddleware = require("../middleware/ValidationMiddleware");

router.post("/", [AuthValidation.login, validationMiddleware], AuthController.loginUser);

module.exports = router;
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const conectarDB = require("./config/DBConfig");
const cors = require("cors");
const errorHandler = require("./middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware");

//Crear el servidor
const app = express();

//Conectar a la BD
conectarDB();

//Habilitar cors
app.use(cors());

//Habilitar express.json
app.use(express.json({ extended: true }));

//Puerto de la app
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4001;

//Rutas
app.use("/api/user", require("./routes/UserRoute"));
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/AuthRoute"));

//Middleware de errores
app.use(errorHandler);

//Arrancar el app
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`El servidor está funcionando en el puerto ${PORT}`);
});
```

The above code works properly, but I have to add `validationMiddleware` for each route. You realize that I wrote `router.post("/", [AuthValidation.login, validationMiddleware], AuthController.loginUser);` in `AuthRoute.js`, but I wouldn't like to add `validationMiddleware` for each route's middlewares. I tried to add `validationMiddleware` in `index.js` like that:

**AuthRoute.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const AuthController = require("../controllers/AuthController");
const AuthValidation = require("../validations/AuthValidation");

router.post("/", [AuthValidation.login], AuthController.loginUser);

module.exports = router;
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const conectarDB = require("./config/DBConfig");
const cors = require("cors");
const errorHandler = require("./middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware");

const validationMiddleware = require("./middleware/ValidationMiddleware");

//Crear el servidor
const app = express();

//Conectar a la BD
conectarDB();

//Habilitar cors
app.use(cors());

//Habilitar express.json
app.use(express.json({ extended: true }));

//Puerto de la app
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4001;

//Rutas
app.use("/api/user", require("./routes/UserRoute"));
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/AuthRoute"));

app.use(validationMiddleware);

//Middleware de errores
app.use(errorHandler);

//Arrancar el app
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`El servidor está funcionando en el puerto ${PORT}`);
});
```

The above code doesn't execute `validationMiddleware`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is where did you use the middleware

```
//Rutas
app.use("/api/user", require("./routes/UserRoute"));
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/AuthRoute"));

app.use(validationMiddleware);
```

the middleware should be **before** the routes:

```
app.use(validationMiddleware);

//Rutas
app.use("/api/user", require("./routes/UserRoute"));
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/AuthRoute"));
```

Comment: ah ok, I see the big picture now... I'll edit the answer